# Solution to Parallel Lithium Batteries with same VSUM but huge SOC difference

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated, charging, battery-chemistry

I have a query regarding charging lithium batteries in parallel. I have attached 3 batteries in parallel set dip switches correctly and connected the com wire to my solar inverter. I did not connect the batteries to the inverter for the next 2–3 hours, so they could balance out. Once they stopped charging each other the SOC was 81, 81 and 84, but I was not worried at this point as it was not a huge difference.

But in morning when PV kicked in batteries started charging at 4000 W and when charging stopped all 3 batteries have same VSUM but SOC is 81, 81 and 94. My questions are:

1. Should I drain all 3 batteries to safe limits of 20% or something and connect again?
2. Should I drain all 3 batteries separately and charge separately again before connecting?

Basically I am afraid that first 2 batteries may keep charging, and third battery will keep charging even if it is at 100% even though BMS should stop the charging at this point but 81 ,81 and 94 is huge SOC difference. Would love any help understanding how to make this correct and how these Lithium batteries work and are behaving this way. Should I ditch BMS and directly use V% to charge and discharge?

[image]

**UPDATE:** Since the time of posting this question. First battery jumped from 81 to 99, second and third are still at 81 and 93.

Comment: I have no idea what SOC means, please explain.

Comment: SOC: State of Charge

Comment: Are all batteries of the same chemistry and same amount of series connected cells? What's the _voltage_ difference between them?

Comment: How do you know the state of charge of your batteries, if your charge controller charges them in parallel? I mean, you can only *observe* a batteries voltage, if you don't have the history of current flowing into it. After all, a battery is really just a metal can with an electrode and electrolyte inside… Or does "battery" mean something different here?

Comment: @winny yes all batteries are of same chemistry and capacity. All three are same models and from same company. Voltage sum remains same since they also charge each other and keep that value same. At this very moment the voltage is 54.66, 54.65 and 54.64. Yet SOC is 99, 81 and 93.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Well all 3 batteries have their own displays as well which shows me the SOC of each battery individually. It is 99, 81 and 93 at this moment. My charge controller shows 91, it is simply summing all three and dividing by 3 to show me AVG percentage.

Comment: then these are not batteries, but something very different. You don't tell us what you're dealing with, then!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I do not know what you call a lithium battery which consists of 16 cells all connected in series and BMS for communication. Is it not a battery?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Is this not a battery, I am very new to using lithium batteries so I am not really sure if I am using wrong terms or if you are just messing with me.

https://sakopower.com/wall-stand-lithium-battery-pack-5kwh-10kwh

Comment: @winny Also the company claims the max voltage to 58.xx and one of the batteries show 54.xx and 99% SOC. Maybe BMS's are still syncing or updating (sorry if I am using wrong terms to explain) since its only been 2 days I connected these batteries for the first time. All three batteries came at 25-26% SOC and I charged all three till 80% individually then connected in parallel to charge controller.

Comment: so, the display is part of a BMS that you didn't mention before.

Comment: I would not trust the SOC reading on any device I haven't written the code for myself. What are the battery voltages measured by you?

Comment: @winny I just checked using volt meter, all three batteries are at around 54.25-54.30. Does this mean BMS is showing incorrect SOC since it shows 99 for once battery, 93 for another and 81 for the third battery when voltage is same for all three?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry about that. I think I assumed all brands use BMS with lithium batteries. Maybe thats why I did not mention. Is it possible that BMS is showing wrong data since it is not possible for BMS to show 99% and 91% for two seperate batteries when voltage is same, any advice?

Comment: That would be my interpretation. There are many ways to implement a SOC readout, most of them flawed. How experienced are you in the dangers of a battery system of this magnitude? It it was my system, I would connect them via a suitable resistor and let them equalize until within 10 mV or less between them before thinking about a hard parallel connection. Is one reading 58.xx on the display yet 54.xx in real life?

Comment: @winny No, I am not experienced at all. Just bought the batteries and, charged seperately and connected together. The voltage on screen and with volt meter is same 54.xx accross all batteries. I am assuming the BMS data is incorrect. Should I stop using BMS mode on my charge controller and just use the batteries with float, bulk etc settings?

Comment: Hard to tell. Live with it and see if the SoC calculation will correct itself over some charge and discharge cycles?

Comment: @winny Hmm, I can try that. In fact I do want to drain the batteries till 10-20% and charge them back in hope that it will all be fixed/balanced on its own.